# Impedance for Helmholtz Coil Connected to Audio Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance, watts, function-generator

I am trying to design a Helmholtz coil, that will have an impedance of about 2 ohms (the reason for this being that I am going to hook it up to a audio power amplifier, so to get the same wattage delivered I'm modeling it like a speaker that is 2 ohms)

If it helps thinking of using [this amplifier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003P198Q8).

First let me detail my set up:

Function Generator -> Power Amplifier -> Helmholtz Coil

I'm trying to generalize this as much as possible, so going to try and talk about it conceptually, is the best way to control the impedance in the coil is to set up an RL circuit, where I have a variable resistor so I can adjust it in turn with the impedance? And should I do the RL circuit in parallel or series?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you add resistive elements, power will be dissipated as heat in those resistors. If you rely on the inductive impedance of the coil, there will be no power transfer at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the impedance of a coil without changing the number or diameter of the windings, varying the length of the coil, or inserting a core.

You can vary the number of windings by constructing a coil with multiple taps. You then get as many different selectable inductances (and hence impedances) as you have taps.