# Decrease Impedance at Higher Frequencies

Tags: capacitor, resistors, amplifier, frequency, impedance

I am trying to see if I understand how impedance works correctly before I build this into a real circuit. Basically I have an inductor (helmholtz coil) driven by a function generator, now by itself we know the higher the freq goes the lower the current the coil will receive. If my understanding is correct, I can put a capacitor in parallel with the coil, which would mean at higher frequencies the Xc would decrease and Xl would increase, but since they are in parallel Xtot should decrease, thus as a result you will get a higher current at the same frequency than if we had just had a inductor (coil) in the circuit by itself. Is this understanding correct? Or is there a smarter way to increase the current my circuit receives at a higher frequency, besides increasing the current outputed by the generator/changing the coil design itself.

p.s. this is a re-expression of the question asked here [Impedance for Helmholtz Coil Connected to Audio Amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29194/impedance-for-helmholtz-coil-connected-to-audio-amplifier) but in a more detailed and precise way I hope

Comment: Looking at my question I think I just asked some variation of what would be the best way to do impedance matching for a higher frequency and thus deliver a higher current, than if I had poor matching? I guess the real concern is to make sure that the resistor or capacitor can withstand the current/power sent through it - since the inductor can

Comment: You possibly trying to stretch the Ohms law with resistance networks into area where impedance is not just an active resistance anymore, but also a reactance. Try the same formulas for parallel networks and you will discover a case with division by zero: infinite impedance to resonant frequency.

Comment: Okay, so maybe want I want to do is instead just add another coil in parallel? Like a choke or something which would then lower the impedance at higher frequencies? Instead of bothering with R and C elements.

Comment: I think you are overanalyzing the problem. The impedance of a speaker is typically very much an active resistance because it is a sort of mechanically loaded motor. Surprizingly there might be no much inductance component in a load. The fall at high frequencies might be caused more by mechanics and less by inductance.

Comment: Oh okay, but what about a helmholtz coil? (the only reason I mention a speaker is cause I am using an audio amplifier to power a helmholtz coil)

Comment: You want to reduce impedance of load: mean you want to transform impedance of load without losses: means you want to use transformer. If coil is 100 Ohm and Amplifier wants 4 Ohm use Audio transformer for 1:25

Comment: Oh okay sweet - thanks a lot, that is what I wanted to do. So then if I have 500 Hz and my coil is 20 ohm impedance do 1:5, 1000 Hz 30 ohm just use something 1:7.5 just wanted to make sure I completely understood it.

Comment: Yes. You understood it exactly for unloaded coil (loop antenna loaded to impedance of infinite empty space ~300 Ohm of vacuum or air). The situation will change if you place a screwdriver into coil opening or frozen frog wrapped into gold leaf or whatever you do withing your experiment. You are not just emitting ultra low frequency radio. But who knows.

Answer (score 3):

> "since they are in parallel Xtot should decrease"

That's not automatically true for complex impedances. For the inductor \$Z_L = j\omega L\$, for the capacitor \$Z_C = \dfrac{1}{j \omega C}\$. Both in parallel gives

\$ Z = \dfrac{j\omega L \cdot \dfrac{1}{j \omega C}}{j\omega L + \dfrac{1}{j \omega C}} = \dfrac{j\omega L \cdot \dfrac{1}{j \omega C}}{\dfrac{j^2 \omega^2 LC + 1}{j \omega C}} = \dfrac{j\omega L}{1 - \omega^2 LC} \$

The minus sign in the denominator is interesting. Since \$\omega^2 LC\$ is positive, we can find a value for it where the denominator becomes zero.

\$ \omega^2 LC = 1\$

or

\$ \omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC}} \$

If the denominator is zero the impedance is infinite. That goes against intuition which says that paralleling two components will give a lower impedance than the lowest of the two.

[image]

The image gives the explanation. Currents through \$C\$ and \$L\$ are at 90° with voltage, but in opposite directions. If their magnitudes are different their sum will be either a capacitive or inductive current. But when they're equal the sum is zero. No current. A zero current for a non-zero voltage means infinite impedance.

The frequency for which this is true is the resonance frequency, and it's used to make oscillators and high-Q filters.

Comment: Thanks - Based on my amplifier that would output 63V (2000 W into 2 ohms), I did \$X_{tot} = X_l X_c / (X_c + X_l)\$ where I have a .01059 Henry coil and a 1.8 uF capacitor in parallel. From this I solve for frequencies between 0 and 50 kHz, resonance will occur at 940 Hz. 

[Wolfram Alpha Calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=63V%2F+%28%28%282*+pi+*+.0159+Henry+*+x+Hz%29+*+%281%2F+%282+*+pi+*+x+Hz+*+1.8+uF%29%29+%29+%2F+%28%282*+pi+*+.0159+Henry+*+x+Hz%29+%2B+%281%2F+%282+*+pi+*+x+Hz+*+1.8+uF%29%29+%29%29)

Does that sound correct given the circuit setup though?

Comment: Though for above \$f_r\$ does \$I_l\$ continue to drop? Because that's what I am trying to prevent from happening.

Comment: Okay I may understand it what I would want to do is put the resonance frequency as high as possible because anything below it would behave like a inductor which is where I want the max current, where as when I pass resonance the circuit becomes capacitive which is not what I want. Maybe?